# Can Tensorflow.js be used for face recognition?

Tags: tensorflow.js

There is a python and C++ api available for doing image recognition.The tutorial is provided in tensorflow.org but as tensorflow.js is released few months back only does it support all the api's available in the python and c++ implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to the answers above, tensorflow on JavaScript can be quite slow. Here's a quick comparison: [image: Comparison]

However, If you do run tensorflow.js on Node, you could make use of the binding directly to the TensorFlow APIs written in C which would be fast. You could also run the CUDA versions if you import the right packages on Node.js

On the browser WebGL is used to run tensorflow. Using the tensorflow or some ML on the browser, opens up whole new opportunities to do things from right within the browser.

As Jirapol suggested, you could take a look at https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/face-api.js which is super easy to use. It actually took a very short while for me to start writing a facial recognition login system on node using face-api.js. Here's a link if you want to take a look at the unfinshed code: https://github.com/WinstonMarvel/face-recognition-authentication

Comment: the benchmark will be different base on the tensorflow back-end. if it's purely javascript then it's terrible. but if it's webgl or super fast webassembly with SIMD then the difference is from earth to the sky

Answer (score 3):

Vincent Mühler has created face-api.js, a JavaScript API base on tensorflow.js. You can find out the blog & code on the links below.

https://itnext.io/face-api-js-javascript-api-for-face-recognition-in-the-browser-with-tensorflow-js-bcc2a6c4cf07

https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/face-api.js

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 1):

> does it support all the api's available in the python and c++ implementation.

No, it still has a limited amount of features. Keep in mind it still in version 0.11.6 so that will change. You can look at the [documentation](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.11.6/) to see what's available.

If you want to port a specific model to tfjs try to get it as a keras model then convert it using [tensorflowjs_converter](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-converter) to a tfjs compatible one like [this tutorial](https://js.tensorflow.org/tutorials/import-keras.html) shows.

There is even a tfjs examples which works with webcam data ([Tutorial](https://js.tensorflow.org/tutorials/webcam-transfer-learning.html), [Live Demo](https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-examples/webcam-transfer-learning/dist/index.html)), so you could look into that to start.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can.

and also with the help of **webassembly** and **SIMD** in the browser.

you can have a ***smooth*** experience of image processing and video processing in the browser.

have a look at this [**link**](https://v8.dev/features/simd) from google v8.

the good news is that with the same api you can run **Tensorflow.js** in the **browser**, **node.js** and **React Native** all with the **native** speed and using native capabilities